# How to calculate data traffic ( internet usage) of ip device through SNMP protocol

Tags: snmp

I have created a snmp manager which will calculate the traffic of a list of ip address.

Here is the snmp walk cammand :

```
  walk snmpwalk = new walk(" 192.168.30.172" ,". 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10", "");
    System.out.println(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," + snmpwalk.doSnmpwalk());
```

Here is the output:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.2=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.3=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.4=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.5=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.6=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.8=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.9=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.10=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.11=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.12=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.13=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.14=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.15=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.16=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.17=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.18=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.19=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.20=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.21=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.22=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.23=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.24=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.25=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.26=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.27=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.28=163292301
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.29=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.30=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.31=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.32=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.33=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.34=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.35=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.36=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.37=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.38=0
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.39=0
```

Now my question is it possible to calculate the traffic(monthly data usage)  at the end of the month of this IP device? 
if possible then how can i do that? What is the formula and calculation process?

Comment: Can you provide a sample walk.txt file (or its representative fragment)? What OS are you using?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bya0QpiG0_7yUHlvVXVWTFExNTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the link of the snmpwalk.txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bya0QpiG0_7yUHlvVXVWTFExNTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i am using windows but the final code will run in linux

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I would use `awk`, e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r"} /::if(In|Out)Octets/{i=$1; sub(/^.*\./,"",i); t[i]+=$4} /::ifDescr/{i=$1; sub(/^.*\./,"",i); d[i]=$4}; END{for(i in t) if(t[i]>0) printf "%s %.2fMB\n",d[i],t[i]/1048576}' Cisco_3750_snmpwalk.txt
```

It sums `ifInOctets` and `ifOutOctets` counters, and displays the sum in MB next to `ifDescr` string if it is greater than 0. Output for your file looks like this:

```
Vlan66 0.00MB
Vlan100 2829.20MB
Vlan117 780.88MB
Vlan230 40.42MB
Vlan237 28.77MB
Vlan242 0.01MB
Vlan302 1902.10MB
Vlan312 181.48MB
Vlan325 738.01MB
Vlan328 253.37MB
Vlan330 0.08MB
Vlan331 590.89MB
Vlan337 320.17MB
Vlan356 3247.89MB
Vlan358 1360.38MB
Vlan362 45.38MB
Vlan364 2179.56MB
Vlan400 0.00MB
Vlan404 105.89MB
Vlan413 157.37MB
Vlan466 3487.25MB
Vlan467 0.00MB
Vlan510 2547.83MB
Vlan548 3033.33MB
Vlan603 0.01MB
Vlan624 0.00MB
Vlan667 0.01MB
Vlan725 1.58MB
Vlan776 103.93MB
Vlan875 29.90MB
Vlan908 15.19MB
Vlan910 27.36MB
Vlan936 13.78MB
Vlan956 13.91MB
Vlan965 68.12MB
Vlan966 298.39MB
Vlan967 167.47MB
Vlan1000 0.00MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/1 5629.52MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/2 4220.78MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/3 6369.15MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/9 3866.67MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/15 5511.63MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/16 6030.57MB
GigabitEthernet1/0/18 4251.62MB
```

Comment: Hi , what i need to do is:  i have to create a snmp manager and agent. then I have to calculate the total usage used by every device in the end of the month . can u plz help me  out ?